# What is the meaning of 'operates transitively'

Tags: algebraic-topology

I read Massey's Algebraic Topology, an introduction.  I can't find the definition of operates transitively.   Seemly, it is not a notion. Since my English is poor, I need help for what is the mean of 'operates transitively'. Thanks very much.

> **Lemma 8.1** Let $(\tilde X, p)$ be a covering space of $X$. The automorphism group $A(\tilde X, p)$ *operates transitively* on $p^{-1}(x)$, $x \in X$, if and only if $(\tilde X, p)$ is a regular covering space of $X$.

Comment: It means that the group action has only one orbit.

Comment: Look for the notion of a transitive group action. That's what it means here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the meaning is that of a transitive group action, ie for any $y, z \in p^{-1}(x)$ there is a $g \in A(\tilde X, p)$, such that $z = gy$.